# Add custom calculation to cart total and grand total in magento

Tags: magento, cart, observers

I am working on site where i want to add/subtract fee to cart total and grand total.I am firing this event to capture the cart details.`sales_order_save_after`. while in observer i got the price using this code

```
public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
        {


       $getotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
       $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); 
       $subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
}.
```

But i don't know how to add/subtract amount from total and than update accordingly.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching i found this tutorial http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-discount-total-magento.And on Discount model class i can add/subtract custom price to cart total like :

```
 public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
            if ($address->getData('address_type') == 'billing')
                return $this;

                $discount = Mage::helper('my_module')->getCurrentdiscount(); // Custom percentage

                $grandTotal = $address->getGrandTotal();
                $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();

                $totals = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());
                $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());

                $address->setFeeAmount(-$totals * $discount / 100);
                $address->setBaseFeeAmount(-$baseTotals * $discount / 100);

                $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal + $address->getFeeAmount());
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: can you please share the detail where do you have added xml,class with paths actually i am trying to add discount in my cart at grand total using your given tutorial link but i am not able understand can you guide me to achieve this i am westing my time from last two days with 0 luck.

Comment: after use this tech. i don't know why coupon code stops working.. can anyone help me. 

what i am doing apply extra fee but if i apply extra fee then if user has couponcode then couponcode stops working..

Comment: @SandeepSingh   I think you can post your question so other members can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Rehman,

i am afraid this is not a straight forward task to complete, although you can take following as Ref to start

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

Hope above link helps.

Comment: i know  that and i already studied that tutorial.they are adding custom price to cart.But in my case the custom price may be percentage or price will be checked run time.So that why i don't go there

Comment: you can change the following line : $fee = Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee(); to whatever calculation you want for the price.. also you cannot get exact solution from web. you may need to tweak/change it a bit according to your problem

Comment: after use this tech. i don't know why coupon code stops working.. can anyone help me. 

what i am doing apply extra fee but if i apply extra fee then if user has couponcode then couponcode stops working..