# Magento: Fixed Amount Discount For Whole Cart For Percentage?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

It says on the Magento website that the 'fixed amount discount for whole cart' applies a percentage discount to the whole cart.

This is not the case. For instance, if I type in 10, the whole cart value will be reduced by £10/$10.

Is there any way to apply discount percentage to the whole cart?

I know I can apply a percentage discount to each unit in the basket, but I want to be able to provide a coupon code to reduce the entire cart by x%, not the pre-VAT product prices.

I'm using 1.7.0.2

***EDIT:***

I think it will be useful to provide an example of what I'm trying to achieve. So, I want to be able to provide people with a coupon code for 15% off the total cart price, after all other discounts have been applied.

For instance, there is currently an offer for 3 items for £22. I want to then reduce the total cart price by 15%, to £18.70.

Any help would be a godsend! Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511309/add-custom-calculation-to-cart-total-and-grand-total-in-magento]

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Thanks for this, but this solution doesn't apply to coupon codes

Comment: Do you want to apply coupons with discount to cart `OR` apply custom discount to cart total ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Hi, I want to apply a coupon with a discount to cart. I'm going to update my question with more information

Comment: @MahmoodRehman I've updated it just now

Answer (score 1):

Check if "Stop Further Rules Processing" is set to "No".
If it set to "Yes", then rule applies only to the price of the first item in cart

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by using simple steps. Just create a coupon at the admin panel by going to Promotions/Catalog Price Rules. Here click "`Add New Rule`" and give all the conditions and details. In the left side u can see option "`Actions`"...

Here you can apply the rule as discount by percentage of fixed value and u can give there ur discount value of 15%. If u dont know of creating coupons in magento, go through this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-a-coupon-code-to-your-promotions