# Is Magento allowed to update table value with custom function?

Tags: magento

I have a function in one page model that will update the value of `grand_total(decimal)` column. My custom variable value is in floating point. My custom update query function is perfectly working with my custom table but not working in magento default table `mg_sales_flat_order`.

Is their any core functionality in magento?

How can I manage this?

**Controller:-** Here `$GrandTotalUpdate` is float number

```
$this->getOnepage()->UpdateGrandTotalAmount($Custome_id,$Get_Quote_Id,$GrandTotalUpdate);
```

**Model function**

```
public function UpdateGrandTotalAmount($Custome_id,$Get_Quote_Id,$GrandTotalUpdate)
    {
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $query = 'UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order SET quote_id='.$Order_Id.' WHERE quote_id ='.$Get_Quote_Id.' AND customer_id='.$Custome_id;
        $write->query($query);

    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511309/add-custom-calculation-to-cart-total-and-grand-total-in-magento . It might help you.

Comment: Thanks you very much.....@ Chiragit007

Comment: Has this work for you ? @mostaq

Comment: This procedure is good , but i am in a place where i need to update grand_total column value using a query.....@Chiragit007

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom calculation to cart total and grand total in magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511309/add-custom-calculation-to-cart-total-and-grand-total-in-magento)